# DeepLink in QRCode with Android 13

Tags: android, kotlin, qr-code, deep-linking

I'm strunggling with deeplinks inside a QRCode.
Before android 13 i havn't issues with it but now my application doesn't be start by the deeplink. The android camera can read the qrcode but when i click on the content it's open the browser and not my App.

Below the activity with the scheme declared in the Manifest

To be clear, i will repeat myself but i have no problems in Android 12 and below

> 

```
<activity
    android:name="com.mypackage.MyAcctivity"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

        <data android:scheme="myScheme" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

<

Thank you for your contribution.

I try to be more specific in my manifest wit pathPrefix or pathSuffix but no changes

**EDIT :** After some tests on other devices it's seems to be a problem with the pixel 6 pro camera.

Comment: any solution? i have same problem

Answer (score 1):

There was a change from Android 13 on and there is now more protection regarding the intents. So all http and https schemas won't be redirected to the app anymore and you need a custom app schema. So it should be something similar to this:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:host="redirect.url"
          android:scheme="yourApp" />
</intent-filter>
```

Also make sure you have

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

in top of the AndroidManifest.xml for the application.

Maybe, to get more insights you could also share your whole AndroidManifest.xml file here so it is easier to see whats going on.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to set targetSDK to 32. But this is not proper solution of course. I didnt find any solution for this problem yet.